# Grant Select ON as

Tags: sql-server

Using SQL Server 2014 I'm trying to execute the following command:

```
GRANT SELECT
    ON OBJECT::[quote_p].[p_quote_fact] TO [SSIS_role]
    AS [dbo];
```

but am getting back the error message:

> Msg 15151, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>
> Cannot find the object 'p_quote_fact', because it does not exist or
>   you do not have permission.

The statement executes fine if I leave off the '`AS [dbo];`'.

Via a Windows group I am a member of the db_owner role.

Reading MSDN page on '[GRANT Database Permissions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178569.aspx)' it states you need the following permissions to use this command:

> IMPERSONATE permission on the user, membership in the db_securityadmin
>   fixed database role, membership in the db_owner fixed database role,
>   or membership in the sysadmin fixed server role.

Based on this I added myself to the 'db_securityadmin' but it made no difference.

Not sure what to try next ... any suggestions as to what I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that I had permissions via a Windows group and as an individual user. As I understand it the latter did not have the required permissions, hence the message.